# Execute sqlplus command execution from System.Diagonistic.process

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, process, sqlplus

I want to take backup of my data using select statement via sqlplus using my asp.net c# application For that I want to open sqlplus and then after want to execute on file named commands.sql which will contain spool command followed by select statement.Now that spool command will take backup of my data into one particular file.I have tried below code but it is not working
Code :-

```
 metricsDump += "conn c##dbname/pwd@orcl$";
            metricsDump += "spool \"" + path + "\\test.txt\";$";
            metricsDump += query + "$";

            metricsDump += "spool off;$";

            metricsDump += "exit;" + "$";

            metricsDump = metricsDump.Replace("$", System.Environment.NewLine);


using (System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
            {

                string in_database = "orcl";
                string s = @"C:\Users\accounts\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\testscenario.sql";
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process.StartInfo.FileName = "sqlplus";
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/ as sysdba conn c##test/test123@orcl @" +s;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;


                    // do process

                    Console.WriteLine(process.StartInfo.Arguments);


                    process.Start();
                    int exitCode = 0;
                    string stdoutx = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                    //string stderrx = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

                    process.WaitForExit();



                    if (process.HasExited)
                    {
                        exitCode = process.ExitCode;
                    }
                    process.Close();

            }
```

But under process.waitfor exit gets into endless loop
In short I want to save (spool) the results into a text file, BUT IT NOT HAPPENING PLEASE HELP ME

Answer (score 1):

I Hope this will help you.  This code will execute your sql file `tobeExecutedSQLFile`  using`cmd.exe` and will generate output `resultTextFilePath`  of the sql file

```
 string asciiQuote = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(34);               
 ExecuteCommand("cmd.exe", "/c exit | sqlplus -S " + dbLink + " @" + asciiQuote + tobeExecutedSQLFile + asciiQuote + " > " + asciiQuote + resultTextFilePath + asciiQuote);


public  string ExecuteCommand(string app, string command)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.FileName = app;            
    startInfo.Arguments = command;
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process = Process.Start(startInfo);    
    while (process.HasExited == false)
    {    
        //process.WaitForExit();               
    }               
    return "Executed";      
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void DropTable()
{
    try
    {
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\sqlplus.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "user/password";
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        process.Start();
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine("@C:\\file.sql");
        process.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```